# Ugly table query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited this table and trying to optimize the queries. I am stuck with one query. Here is the table information

- RaterName - varchar(24) - name of the rater
- TimeTaken - varchar(12) - is stored as 00:10:14:8
- Year - char(4) - is stored as 2014

I need

1. distinct list of raters, total count for the rater, `sum(TimeTaken)` for rater, `avg(timetaken)` for rater (for a given year)
2. I also need `sum(timetaken)` and `avg(TimeTaken)` for all the raters (for a given year)

Here is the query that I have come up with for #1... I would like the sum and avg to be like hh:mm:ss. How can I do this?

```
SELECT 
      [RaterName]
      , count(*) as TotalRatings
      , SUM((DATEPART(hh,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))*60)+DATEPART(mi,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))+(DATEPART(ss,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))/(60.0)))/60.0  as TotalTimeTaken
      , AVG((DATEPART(hh,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))*60)+DATEPART(mi,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))+(DATEPART(ss,convert(datetime, timetaken, 101))/(60.0)))/60.0  as AverageTimeTaken
  FROM 
      [dbo].[rating]
  WHERE 
      year = '2014'
  GROUP BY 
      RaterName
  ORDER BY 
      RaterName
```

Output:

```
RaterName   TotalRatings    TotalTimeTaken  AverageTimeTaken
================================================================
Rater1          257     21.113609   0.082154
Rater2          747     41.546106   0.055617
Rater3          767     59.257218   0.077258
Rater4          581     37.154163   0.063948
```

Can I incorporate #2 in this query or write a second query and drop group by from it?

On the front end, I am using C#.

Comment: If you need to incorporate `#2` why don't you add that to your existing query also change where you re hard coding the `year = 2014` create a stored procedure to handle this as an Input param.

Comment: This will be a SP once i have the working query. So for #1, i still need to change this into hh:mm:ss and i am having a little bit of a hard time.

Comment: I would also investigate making columns reflect their actual data types, datetime for the time and smallint for the year. SQL has to convert each value before it runs the calculations which can cause a lot of overhead.

Comment: do a Google search on GETDATE Function along with Convert here is a starting point http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Date-Timezone/CONVERTvarcharGETDATE108hhmmss.htm

Comment: @MethodMan, what would it have to do with getdate()?

Comment: @CetinBasoz check out the link I sent an you can answer that question for yourself.

Comment: I did but couldn't understand a bit why you would have suggested that and asked to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    WITH  data ( raterName, timeTaken )
            AS (
                 SELECT raterName,
                        DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST('00:00' AS TIME),
                                 CAST(timeTaken AS TIME))
                 FROM   rating
                 WHERE  CAST([year] AS INT) = 2014
               )
      SELECT  raterName, COUNT(*) AS totalRatings,
              SUM(timeTaken) AS totalTimeTaken, avg(timeTaken) AS averageTimeTaken
FROM data
      GROUP BY raterName
      ORDER BY raterName;
```

PS: If you don't want milliseconds, can make that Second or Minute.
EDIT: On your C# frontend you can make the Milliseconds or Seconds to a TimeSpan which would give you the format when you use ToString. ie:

```
var ttt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalTimeTaken).ToString();
```

Comment: Its missing `From data`, i have edited and updated the query

Comment: A quick question regarding totalTimeTaken and timespan. Total time taken for all the raters is `1954980212`. Now when i use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(report.TotalTimeTakenMilliseconds)ToString` as proposed, i get `22.15:03:00.2120000`. And when i use `.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(report.TotalTimeTakenMilliseconds).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")`, i get `15:03:00`. This is wrong, my total time should be around 510:16:38 (quick manual calculation). I am obviously missing some thing here.